# Tkinter Entry to store into a variable returns nothing

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Ok so I have been trying to get user input from an entry with Tkinter and store it into a variable that is printed at the end of the program, but when the variable is printed, the output is the initial value.

The code:

```
from tkinter import *
hello = ''
root = Tk()

e = Entry(root, width = 50)
e.pack()
def myClick():
    hello = e.get()
button1 = Button(root, text = 'ik', command = myClick)
button1.pack()
root.mainloop()
print(hello)
```

Comment: `hello` in the function `myClick` is not the same variable as `hello` on global. You can use `global` keyword in the function.

Comment: I use global like: global.hello = e.get()?

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) and [Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29158947/7414759)

Answer (score 0):

The `hello` variable in myClick is a local variable. To get it to refer to the global variable you need to declare it as global.

```py
def myClick():
    global hello
    hello = e.get()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't think of that.